# Function to sum each grid cells of raster stack using other rasters as an indicator

Tags: r, raster

```
## input raster
s <- stack(list.files("~/dailyraster", full.names=TRUE)) # daily raster stack
r_start <- raster("~/stackSumSTART.asc") # this raster contain starting Julian day
r_end <- raster("~/stackSumEND.asc") # this raster contain ending Julian day
noNAcells <- which(!is.na(r[])) # cell numbers which contain values

## dummy raster
x <- r
x[] <- NA 

## loop
for (i in noNAcells) {      
  x[i] <- sum(s[[r_start[i]:r_end[i]]][i])
}
```

I would like to create a function like `stackApply()`, but I want it to work on a cell basis.

Above is a `for()` loop version and it works well, but it takes too much time.

The point is that each cell gets the range of `sum()` from two raster layers, `r_start`, `r_end` in above script.

Now I am struggling to transform this code using `apply()` family.

Is there any possibility to improve the speed with `for()` loop? or please give me some tips to write this code in `apply()`

Any comments will help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your approach

```
x <- s$layer.1

system.time(
for (i in 1:ncell(x)) {
     x[i] <- sum(s[[r_start[i]:r_end[i]]][i], na.rm = T)
   }
)
```

> ```
>    user  system elapsed 
>   0.708   0.000   0.710
> ```

### My proposal

You can add the rasters used as indices at the end of your stack and then use `calc` to highly speed up the process (~30-50x).

```
s2 <- stack(s, r_start, r_end)
sum_time <- function(x) {sum(x[x[6]:x[7]], na.rm = T)}

system.time(
   output <- calc(s2, fun = sum_time)
)
```

> ```
>    user  system elapsed 
>   0.016   0.000   0.015
> ```

```
all.equal(x, output)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

### Sample Data

```
library(raster)

# Generate rasters of random values
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- r4 <- r5 <- r_start <- r_end <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)

r1[] <- rnorm(ncell(r1), 1, 0.2)
r2[] <- rnorm(ncell(r2), 1, 0.2)
r3[] <- rnorm(ncell(r3), 1, 0.2)
r4[] <- rnorm(ncell(r4), 1, 0.2)
r5[] <- rnorm(ncell(r5), 1, 0.2)
s <- stack(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)

r_start[] <- sample(1:2, ncell(r_start),replace = T)
r_end[] <- sample(3:5, ncell(r_end),replace = T)
```

Comment: Thank you so much DJack!

Comment: I have some following questions.
I modified the `sum_time()` like

`sum_time2 <- function(x) {sum(x[x[ifelse(nlayers(x)==7, 6, 7)]:x[ifelse(nlayers(x)==7, 7, 8)]], na.rm = T)}`

But console returns error `cannot use this function`. 
When I use `nlayers(s2)`, except `nlayers(x)` in `ifelse()` function (which is little weired), it works.
I think there is some rule to define or to use a function that I do not know.

Comment: Within the function, `x` is a vector corresponding to the values of each raster in the stack, for one cell. It means that you should use `length(x)` in place of `nlayers(x)`. Having said that, adding this function will (slightly) decrease the speed of `calc`. It's better to store  `a = nlayers(s2) - 1` and `b = nlayers(s2)` before calling `calc` and define the function as `sum(x[x[a]:x[b]]`.