# Sum conditioned through raster stack in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a group 34 raster (.tif), of approximate 10MB each, with values ​​1 and 0 of presence or absence of Eucalyptus respectively, product of a supervised classification of the same area and identical. Each raster represents a year of evaluation (i) from 1985 to 2018. I want to find the sum of two types of pixel sequences in groups of three images:

1. stable pixels: the value of the pixel is 1 in the year (i), (i + 1)
   e (i-1) and corresponds to a sequence of 111. That is to say that
   for consecutive years it is Eucalyptus.
2. unstable pixels: it is 1 in
       year i and 0 in year i + 1 and year i-1 (sequence 010). That is to
       say that it is alternately Eucalyptus and in other years it is not,
       which can be a classification error.

In both cases, the aim is to verify if the classification is robust, beyond the high kappa indexes resulting from the classification.
My questions are:

1. How can I implement this process in R?
2. I read that maybe the loop with "for" is not the best option to work with large rasters, is there another alternative? Because I have to implement other processes with similar logics.

I tried several alternatives based on: [Function to sum each grid cells of raster stack using other rasters as an indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870389/function-to-sum-each-grid-cells-of-raster-stack-using-other-rasters-as-an-indica) or here [Conditionally calculating the difference between max(raster) and each raster layer of raster stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55946554/conditionally-calculating-the-difference-between-maxraster-and-each-raster-lay) but I do not understand its logic very well.
The same problem I could solve with QGIS with the "Field Calculator" and it works well (it is tedious and feasible of errors) in the following way:

Stable pixel = ("img1985 @ 1" = 1 AND "img1986 @ 1" = 1 AND "img1987 @ 1" = 1) + ... + ("img2016 @ 1" = 1 AND "img2017 @ 1" = 1 AND "img2018 @ 1" = 1)

Unstable pixel = ("img1985 @ 1" = 0 AND "img1986 @ 1" = 1 AND "img1987 @ 1" = 0) + ... + ("img2016 @ 1" = 0 AND "img2017 @ 1" = 1 AND "img2018 @ 1" = 0)

Where to imgYear: is each raster of each year; 1985 ... 2018: year

````
```
library(raster)
# Initial sample data + result
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- r4 <- r5 <- rUns <- rSta <- raster(matrix(0, 10, 10))

# Create some "stable pixels" of example.
for (i in seq(from=10, to=50, by=10)) {
r1[(i+6):(i+10)] <- 1
r2[(i+6):(i+10)] <- 1
r3[(i+6):(i+10)] <- 1
r4[(i+6):(i+10)] <- 1
r5[(i+6):(i+10)] <- 1
}
# Create some "unstable pixels" of example.
r2 [c(60,70,80)] <- 1
r3 [1] <- 1
r4 [c(60,70,80)] <- 1
# Stack raster
r <- stack(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)

# *** Expected results ***
# Sum of stable pixels (Sta)
for (i in 2:nlayers(r)) {
pixelSta <- ((r[[i-1]] == 1) * (r[[i]] == 1) * (r[[i+1]] == 1))* 1
}
# Don't work: Error in .local(x, ...) : not a valid subset
# *** Result Expected (rSta): sequence 111. Manually.
for (i in seq(from=10, to=50, by=10)) {
rSta[(i+6):(i+10)] <- 3
}
as.matrix(rSta)

# Sum of unstable pixels (Uns)
for (i in 2:nlayers(r)) {
pixelUns <- ((r[[i-1]] == 0) * (r[[i]] == 1) * (r[[i+1]] == 0))* 1
}
# Don't work: Error in .local(x, ...) : not a valid subset
# *** Result Expected (rUns): sequence 010. Manually.
rUns [c(60,70,80)] <- 2
rUns [1] <- 1
as.matrix(rUns)
```
````

The expected results are in the code (*** Result Expected, manually).`

Thank you very much in advance and I hope I have been clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a simple function that computes (in)stability. For example, function `f`

```
f <- function(x) sum(diff(x)==0)
```

computes the number of steps that are not transitions from one state to another.

Try it

```
f(c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
#[1] 5
f(c(0,0,0,0,1,1))
#[1] 4
f(c(0,1,0,1,0,1))
#[1] 0
```

Now with Raster data

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
s <- stack(s, s)
x <- calc(s, f)
plot(x)
```

Comment: My apologies for delaying the answer, I think the question was not clear. His answer gave me a good idea of how to solve it, like this:
`sum ((diff (c (0,0,1,0,1,1,0), differences = 2) == -2))`
This adds up the differences applied 2 times for "unstable pixels" 0,1,0.
For "stable pixels" (1,1,1):
`sum ((diff (c (0,0,1,1,1,1,0), differences = 2) == 0))`
In short, it is about finding common patterns of "diff" for combinations of n values (in my case n = 3: 0,1,0 or 1,1,1).
I have not applied it to images yet, so I do not know whether to close the question. Thank you!